# Infinite derivative of nested radicals

Tags: derivatives, nested-radicals

$$\cdots \frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x+\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[4]{x\cdots}}}$$ Its not super hard to find a finite number of derivatives, but I can not understand how to pull off infinite here. Please help. Thank you.(Is it even logical?)

Comment: In your question, what is $y$ ?

Comment: Since the derivative of the answer is the same as the answer, this must be a multiple of $e^x$. That is, if this makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function
\begin{align}
S_{n}(x) = \sqrt[2]{x + \sqrt[3]{x + \sqrt[4]{x + \cdots + \sqrt[n+2]{x}}}}
\end{align}
For the case of $S_{2}(x)$ then
\begin{align}
D S_{2}(x) &= D\left[ \sqrt[2]{x + \sqrt[3]{x + \sqrt[4]{x}}} \, \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \, S_{2}(x) } \, \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{3 \, \left( \sqrt[3]{x + \sqrt[4]{x}} \right)^{2}} \, \left( 1 + \frac{1}{4 \, \sqrt[4]{x^{3}}} \right) \right]
\end{align}
Further differentiation can be applied. If this problem was found in a book the line "...an exercise left for the reader." is applied.